# how translate.csv affect the frontend product page?

Tags: frontend

My product page have a labels like `Qty:` , `My Cart` and others and I want to translate these text fields with translate.csv file in my theme folder `(app / design / frontend / FOLDER / THEME / locale / pt_BR / translate.csv)`, but to have created the pt_BR folder and cleared the cache after inserting the file, the display on the product page continues the native language of theme (english) i want to change to portuguese-brasilian.

Part of my code is:

```
"Video", "Video"
"Information", "Informação"
"Special products" and "Produtos Especiais"
"Qty", "Quant."
"Mage_Catalog :: Add to Cart", "Adicionar ao carrinho"
"Mage_Checkout :: Add to Cart", "Adicionar ao carrinho"
```

How do you translate correctly?

Answer (score 2):

When adding a module in front of a string spaces should be omitted

```
"Mage_Catalog::Add to Cart", "Adicionar ao carrinho"
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto **AdminPanel >> System > Configuration > General > Design > Themes >> Translations**

Add your theme name in your configuration and save, further check frontend.